# Java преобразование типов

Tags: java

как можно строку или набор charов состоящую из `0` и `1` перевести в `boolean`?Вроде в с++ это было легко сделать,т.к. `0=false`,остальное=`true`,а тут сложности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
boolean[] mass = new boolean[charArray.length];

for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++){
    if (charArray[i] == '0')
        mass[i] = false;
    else
        mass[i] = true;
}
```

как-то так в лоб

---

Можно без массива символов

```
boolean[] mass = new boolean[string.length];

for(int i=0; i<string.length; i++){
    if (string.charAt(i) == '0')
        mass[i] = false;
    else
        mass[i] = true;
}
```

---

Отличный вариант предложила **@diraria**

```
boolean[] mass = new boolean[string.length];

for(int i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        mass[i] = string.charAt(i) != '0' ;
}
```

Comment: вместо `if`/`else` можно написать `mass[i] = charArray[i] == '1'`

Comment: отличное предложение, добавлю в ответ от вашего имени =) только не =='1', должно быть не равно 0. В соответствии с условием "0=false,остальное=true"

Comment: очевидное рядом,спасибо))

Comment: Хочется добавить, что С++ тип String представляется, как массив char'ов, когда в Java это самостоятельный тип, который имеет api отличный от api array